# SoundCloud like waveform-seekbar?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, waveform, android-seekbar

Here is an image of the sound cloud's seek bar:
[image]

Sound cloud actually calculates the waveform before the song plays and adds it as the background for the seek bar.

I have tried to add some visualization based on [android-visualizer](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer). But what I need is to use the visualizer as the background for the audio seekbar. Any pointers would be really usefull, as I am sure that there might be some code to begin with.

Thank you.

Comment: FYI. Soundcloud builds the wave form LONG before it played. It is stored on the server as a PNG, and available via Their API. It is not built on the fly.

Comment: Now that makes sense. I was wasting a ton of my time visualizing the audio before its played!! Thank you @szatmary

Comment: @szatmary But when we record a sound in soundcloud, it generates waveform on run time.

Comment: This answer is a year old. Things change. They are probably generating it locally while recording to preview. But once uploaded, it is done again server side (to avoid people uploading incorrect waveform images). But im just guessing

Comment: [**AndroidWave-ProgressBar**](https://github.com/alxrm/audiowave-progressbar) is a library available on the git which might be help full for you. and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781128/how-to-get-a-soundcloud-like-waveforms-in-android).