# How to create a wave form image from Audio File in Android?

Tags: android, audio, data-visualization, waveform

I am having a audio file and I want to create the waveform Image of that file so that whenever I play the file only the color is filled in that wave form.

This is the type of image I want to create from Audio file. I have researched about it a lot but cannot find anything.

[image]

Comment: downvoter comment the reason

Comment: I'm very interested in this. Any update?

Comment: @Aracem https://stackoverflow.com/a/38782544/5771946

Comment: that answer resolve nothing, it talks about the draw methods, the easy part, but who to get quickly the amplitudes from a .mp3?

Comment: I finally use ffmpeg to resolve it. It's not fast but it's enough